# Turtle Graphics program. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: c, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to do an exercise which is here (page 246 number 6.23) http://index-of.es/C++/C%20How%20to%20Program.pdf. My code printf a 12x12 square but instead my code prints a 25x25 square but with the left side formed half by 1's and the other half by 0's. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50

int main(){
    int lifted=1, floor[50][50]={0}, commands[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,9}, spaces, command, north=1, south=0, east=0, west=0, row=25, column=25, i, max=1;


    while(command!=9){
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        scanf("%d",&command);
        switch(command){
            case 1:
                lifted=1;
                break;
            case 2: 
                lifted=0;
                break;
            case 3:
                if(north==1){
                    north=0;
                    east=1;
                }else if(south==1){
                    south=0;
                    west=1;
                }else if(west==1){
                    north=1;
                    west=0;
                }else if(east==1){
                    south=1;
                    east=0;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(north==1){
                    north=0;
                    west=1;
                }else if(south==1){
                    south=0;
                    east=1;
                }else if(west==1){
                    west=0;
                    south=1;
                }else if(east==1){
                    north=1;
                    east=0;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Enter a number of spaces: ");
                scanf("%d",&spaces);
                max=spaces;
                break;
            case 6:
                for(i=0; i<50; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<50; j++){
                        printf("%d ",floor[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                exit(0);

        }
        if(lifted==0){
            for(i=0; i<max; i++){
                if(north==1){
                    row--;
                }else if(south==1){
                    row++;
                }else if(east==1){
                    column++;
                }else if(west==1){
                    column--;
                }
                floor[row][column]=1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The output doesn't draw a 12x12 square. Why? Please help me. Basically I don't know what to do. Can someone find the mistake? I've been on this exercise for over a day now. Thank you.

Comment: Please - post important parts of task here. Not everyone is comfortable with visiting some random pages on the Internet...

Comment: _"The output doesn't draw a 12x12 square"_. So what does it draw instead? Show the expected and the actual ouput for a given input sample.

Comment: You have to be a little more specific than "My code doesn't work." In what way does it not work and what have you done to narrow down the problem?

Comment: The link goes to a PDF copy of *C - How to Program* (6th edition) by Deitel & Deitel.

Comment: @melpomene I've added the page and the number of the exercise.

Comment: The first bug in your program is at `while(command!=9)`: `command` is not initialized.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you but it doesn't solve the main problem.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, it is. `...spaces, *command*, north=1, ...`

Comment: @SvenKrüger That's not an initialization.

Comment: @melpomene Do you mean "definition" in opposite to "declaration"?... @user10198594 You define `row=25` and `column=25`. I think, you have adjust those values, but I cannot spot the exact place and way in your source code right now.

Comment: @SvenKrüger No, I mean what I said: initialization.

Comment: @SvenKrüger The exercise tells me that the turtle has to start walking from the centre...

Comment: That made it worse: `commands[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,9}` you need a single integer, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output doesn't print a 12x12 square because the following code prints 50 lines with 50 numbers on each.

```
            for(i=0; i<50; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<50; j++){
                    printf("%d ",floor[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
```

The reason for the apparently corrupted output you describe in the original question is probably something to do with this code:

```
    if(lifted==0){
        for(i=0; i<max; i++){
            if(north==1){
                row--;
            }else if(south==1){
                row++;
            }else if(east==1){
                column++;
            }else if(west==1){
                column--;
            }
            floor[row][column]=1;
        }
    }
```

This is performing an **unchecked** array access, which can result in undefined behavior, including overwriting pieces of memory that should not be written to by this code. That could account for all sorts of weird results.
To protect against that, you'll need to add four checks, one for each edge of the 50x50 grid. For example:

```
if(north==1){
    if(--row < 0){
        row = 0;
    }
}else if(south==1) ...
```